# How to code a sum in Mathematica and how to solve it?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, summation

I'm trying to find the coefficients of the Radau IIA Runge Kutta Implicit scheme.

Those Runge Kutta schemes have Butcher tableau consisting of Cs, As, and Bs.
[article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Radau_IIA_methods)

I have already computed the Cs as such successfully:

```
P[x_, s_] := {v = 2*x - 1; LegendreP[s, v] - LegendreP[s - 1, v]}

s = 3;
c =  Solve[P[x, s] == 0, x];
c = RotateLeft[c, {1}]
```

However, in order to find the As and subsequently the Bs, I need to solve the below equation which I originally posted:

I have the following equation and I need to code it and then solve it for $a_{ij}$:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^s a_{ij}c_{j}^{q-1} = \frac{c_{i}^q}{q};\quad i = 1, ..., s;\quad q = 1, ..., s
$$

Assume that $c_{n}$ is a previous existing list.

My attempt is as follows:

```
(*Array[a, {s,s}]*)

func[a_, s_] := Sum[Sum[Sum[a[[i, j]]*c[[j]]^(k - 1), {j, 1, s}] - (c[[i]]^k)/k, {i,1, s}], 
{k, 1, s}]

d = N[Solve[func[a, s] == 0, a], 100]
```

Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's take a short example with $s=3$.

```
c = {4, 8, 2};
s = Length[c];

eqs = Catenate@
  Table[Sum[a[i, j] c[[j]]^(q - 1), {j, 1, s}] == c[[i]]^q/q, {i, 1, 
    s}, {q, 1, s}];

Solve[eqs, Catenate@Table[a[i, j], {i, 1, s}, {j, 1, s}]]
(* {{a[1, 1] -> -(539/135), a[1, 2] -> 227/270, a[1, 3] -> -(2/135), ... }} *)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting the required results. I'm editing my question and giving out the real question.

Comment: It does solve the equation! But how do I connect the c that was already calculated to this piece of code. In your example, you actually wrote down the numbers: " {1,2,3} " but my c result is as such: " {{ 1}, {2}, {3} } "

Comment: ``c = Flatten[{ {1}, {2}, {3} }]``

Answer (score 7):

This can of course be formulated as a linear-algebraic problem. Using Domen's example:

```
With[{c = {4, 8, 2}},
     Transpose[LinearSolve[Table[c^(q - 1), {q, Length[c]}],
                           Table[c^q/q, {q, Length[c]}]]]]
   {{-(2/3), 2/9, 40/9}, {8/3, 16/9, 32/9}, {-(11/6), 5/18, 32/9}}
```

Note that the matrix on the left of the `LinearSolve[]` is what is also known as a [Vandermonde matrix](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VandermondeMatrix.html).

---

Since the OP brings up the Radau IIA implicit Runge-Kutta method, here's how to get the non-redundant parts of its Butcher tableau (here, I use `5` to correspond to the 5th-order method):

```
With[{s = Quotient[5 + 1, 2]},
     sol = Sort[x /.
                Solve[(x - 1) JacobiP[s - 1, 0, 1, 1 - 2 x] == 0, x],
                Less];
     {sol, 
      Transpose[LinearSolve[Table[sol^(q - 1), {q, s}], 
                            Table[sol^q/q, {q, s}]]]}] // Apart
   {{2/5 - Sqrt[3/2]/5, 2/5 + Sqrt[3/2]/5, 1},
    {{11/45 - 7/(60 Sqrt[6]), 37/225 - 169/(300 Sqrt[6]), -(2/225) + Sqrt[2/3]/25},
     {37/225 + 169/(300 Sqrt[6]), 11/45 + 7/(60 Sqrt[6]), -(2/225) - Sqrt[2/3]/25},
     {4/9 - 1/(6 Sqrt[6]), 4/9 + 1/(6 Sqrt[6]), 1/9}}}
```

and compare with the result in the wiki page linked in the OP.

Comment: ...and for the lazy: ``NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKuttaRadauIIACoefficients[5, ∞]``

Comment: How long does it take to compute for the 17th order using your code above?

Comment: For something that large, I would use a different method: ``With[{s = Quotient[17 + 1, 2]}, sol = Sort[x /. Solve[(x - 1) JacobiP[s - 1, 0, 1, 1 - 2 x] == 0, x], Less]; {sol, LinearAlgebra`Private`VandermondeSolve[sol, #, "Transposed" -> True] & /@ Transpose[Table[sol^q/q, {q, s}]]} // RootReduce]``

Comment: What about the code above with "catenate table"? I've already done this in Python! I just didn't know how to code it in Mathematica. I'm not good at Mathematica coding. That's why I'm asking which code from the replies I got is the fastest and most accurate to find the 17th Order.

Comment: We are dealing with exact quantities here, so there is no issue of "accuracy" involved, unless you had replaced `Solve[]` with `NSolve[]`. I haven't had the time to experiment with Domen's method, so it's a speed comparison you might wish to do yourself.

Comment: Domen's method is taking ages to compute, even though I got the C coeff as soon as the computation started. I'm gonna try your second one now. :)

Comment: Are you sure, that the second code is correct? It looks like it is missing this: "Table[sol^(q - 1), {q, s}"

Comment: That would be because ``LinearAlgebra`Private`VandermondeSolve[]`` only needs the generating vector of the underlying Vandermonde matrix, so in principle, it should work faster than `LinearSolve[]`, which needs to have the full matrix assembled.